# Proving $|x|^{-\alpha} \in W^{1,p}(U)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I am working on an example in Evans' PDE book, Sobolev Spaces, Section 5.2.2 Definition of Sobolev Space, Example 3. There is a small part that bothers me. Here is the example and my confusion.

> Example $3$. Take $U = B^0(0,1)$, the open unit ball in
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $$   u(x) = |x|^{-\alpha} \quad (x \in U, \ x \neq
> > 0) $$
>   For which values of $\alpha > 0,n,p$ does $u$ belong to $W^{1,p}(U)$? (Here $W^{k,p}(U)$ is the Sobolev space on $U$.)

The answer is 
$$
u \in W^{1,p}(U) \iff \alpha < \frac{n-p}{p}
$$
The steps to show this is

1. When $0\leq\alpha + 1 < n$ we can show (by taking an $\epsilon$ ball and taking the limit)
   $$
   \int_U u\phi_{x_i}dx = - \int_U u_{x_i} \phi dx
   $$
   for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(U)$
2. $|Du(x)| = \frac{\alpha}{|x|^{\alpha+1}} \in L^p(U)$ if and only if $(\alpha +1)p < n$
3. Therefore $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$ if and only if $\alpha < \frac{n-p}{p}$

**My question**

I am good with step 1. For step 2 and 3, I can show when $\alpha < \frac{n-p}{p}$ the result holds.

What I don't understand is: for the other direction shouldn't I check when does $|D_{x_i}(u)| \in L^p(U)$ hold for $i=1,\cdots,n$? When I look at the definition of Sobolev spaces it says:

> "for every multiindex $\beta$ with $|\beta| \leq k$ (in our case
>   $k=1$), $D^\beta u$ exists and belongs to $L^p(U)$"

Instead of this the book checks when does $|Du| \in L^p(U)$ i.e. checks if the gradient of $u$ is $L^p$. Is this somehow equivalent to what I want to check?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\int |\partial_{x_i} u|^p \leq \int |D u|^p
\end{align}
which mean if the gradient is in $L^p$ then the partials are also in $L^p$.

Comment: I got that part, my question is the other direction. For the partials in $L^p$ the gradient doesn't necessarily be in $L^p$.

Comment: Just use triangle inequality.

Comment: Okay now I see, thanks.